# Функция, выполняющая схожие действия с данными различных типов

Tags: c++

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как (и можно ли вообще это сделать) написать одну функцию выполняющую схожие действия(арифметические, логические и т.п.) над данными разных типов. Вид действия при возможности тоже неплохо бы менять(если язык это позволяет конечно). Если можно, приведите пару примеров

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Класический пример сравнения двух переменных с предикатом:
Два предиката:

```
template<class T>
class CMPLess
{
public:
    bool operator() (T a, T b) { return a<b; }
};

template<class T>
class CMPEqual
{
public:
    bool operator() (T a, T b) { return a==b; }
};
```

Функция сравнения:

```
template<class T, class CMP>
bool equal_if(T a, T b, CMP cmp)
{
    return cmp(a,b);
}
```

Вызов:

```
int a=2, b=3;
if (equal_if(a, b, CMPLess<int>()))
{ 
    // a<b
}
else
if (equal_if(a, b, CMPEqual<int>()))
{ 
    // a==b
}
```

В этом примере не только типы не определены, так еще и действие, которое производится в функции **equal_if**, неизвестно пока не будет вызова этих функций.

**UPD**: Обновление для того, чтобы минимизировать упоминание типов. В примере выше передается параметром **CMPEqual<int>()**, спрашивается зачем указывать тип явно, если его можно вывести неявно из типа переменных **a** и **b**. Вот как это можно сделать:

Меняем функцию сравнения:

```
template<template<class> class CMP, class T>
bool equal_if(T a, T b)
{
    return CMP<T>()(a,b);
}
```

Вызов меняется так, что явно типы указываются только при создании переменных:

```
int a=2, b=3;
if (equal_if<CMPLess>(a, b))
{ 
    // a<b
}
```

Comment: Извините, что задаю вопрос в комментарии, просто не смогу нормально сформулировать его без приведенного в этом ответе материала. Можно ли не прописывать тип при использовании шаблона (в данном случае <int>) явно, при написании кода, т.е. может ли он динамически меняться ? Если нет, то в чем отличие от макросов ?

Comment: @avp по поводу указания типа при использовании шаблона смотрите обновление ответа. Динамически (т.е. во время исполнения программы) тип меняться, разумеется, не может. Поскольку инстанцирование (генерация) шаблона происходит при компиляции. Отличие от макросов во многом, например, строгой типизацией, поддержкой перегрузки и много еще чем (читайте литаратуру - про это очень много уже писано-переписано).

Comment: Спасибо. Не кажется ли Вам, что все подобные штуки (равно как и сложные макросы) "затуманивают" программу ? Особенно, когда надо править чужой код.

Comment: @avp напротив, ООП особенно в исполнении на C++ придает стройность программе, и результирующий код может быть очень простым. Как Matrix a,b; a+=b; В результает получаем код, который можно использовать повторно, причем программисту которые не знает ни алгебры и даже что такое матрица или как в примере со сравнением - программист использующий equal_if не обязан знать как пишутся шаблоны, ему нужен только пример его вызова.

Comment: @JAZ ! Я не собираюсь полемизировать, скорее просто жалуюсь. Все мы делаем ошибки и, к сожалению, люди пишущие внутренности тоже. Добавьте хроническое отсутствие документации и станет понятно, что изловить нетривиальную ошибку в этом коде м.б. сложнее, чем в спегетти из goto.

Comment: @avp, во первых IAZ, во вторых я не полемезирую а привожу аргументы в пользу ООП. Нетривиальную ошибку отловить всегда сложно, на то она и нетривиальная. Но не нужно быть асом программирования, чтобы отловить ошибку в сложении двух матриц, когда это сложение написано в одной процедуре, и ее код не перемешан по всей программе в виде бесконечных переходов goto.

Comment: Извините @IAZ. Спасибо за объяснение шаблонов. Кстати, в примере с Matrix это перегрузка операции или применение шаблонов ?

Comment: @avp не имея этого класса мы не можем сказать однозначно :) Лично я бы писал класс Matrix шаблонным и не исключено, что перегруженные операторы были бы тоже шаблонными.

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов два.

1) перегрузка функций. Это означает, что мы делаем N функций с одним и тем же именем, но разными типами входных данных. Но при этом нужно быть внимательным. Т.е. так сделать можно, но череповато:

```
char add(char,char);
int add(int,int);
double add(double,double);

//... где-то в коде
int x=10, y=0;
std::cout<<x<<"+"<<y<<add((double)x,y);
// так какой же вариант ф-ции выбрать!?
// а так работает:
std::cout<<x<<"+"<<y<<add((double)x,(double)y);
```

2) использование шаблонов. Шаблоны это очень занятно. По факту шаблон разворачивается в реальный код по месту использования его в коде. Поэтому код пухнет, но зато обеспечивается гибкость.